# Optional.orElse does not compile with anonymous types

Tags: java, option-type, anonymous-class

I encountered a weird problem using `Optional`s and anonymous classes:

```
public class Foo {
    interface Bar {
    }

    void doesNotCompile() {
        Optional.of(new Bar() {
        }).orElse(new Bar() {
        });
    }

    void doesNotCompile2() {
        final Bar bar = new Bar() {
        };
        Optional.of(new Bar() {
        }).orElse(bar);
    }

    void compiles1() {
        final Bar bar = new Bar() {
        };
        Optional.of(bar).orElse(new Bar() {
        });
    }
}
```

The first two methods do not compile with the error

```
java: incompatible types: <anonymous test.Foo.Bar> cannot be converted to <anonymous test.Foo.Bar>
```

I'd expected that, since both implement the interface `Bar` all three approaches work. I also cannot figure out why the third option fixes the problem. Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: The third one fixes the problem, because there the type of `Optional.of` is fixed to `Optional<Bar>`. In all the other cases, it is `Optional<SubAnonymousSubclassOfBar>`. I would have expected the other two to type-infer the appropriate common upper-bound of `Bar` as well, though. But apparently `Optional<SomeSubclassOfBar>(bar).orElse(someOtherSubclassOfBar)` needs some hand-holding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can supplement the type on the first two using a type witness:

```
Optional.<Bar>of(new Bar(){}).orElse(new Bar(){});
```

This allows the compiler to see that you are expecting a return of `Optional<Bar>`, which #orElse can then inferr to accepting any `Bar`

Answer (score 5):

You'd need to tell the Optional that you want a Bar for that interface.

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
Optional<Bar> o = Optional.of(new Bar() {}).orElse(bar);
```

Comment: I know what generics are for. I just thought javac will infer the types as @Thilo said.

Comment: Yeah, coming from Scala, having to spell this out is kind of lame. On the other hand, `javac` compiles so much faster, so ...

Comment: @Mirco it infers 'anon type extending Bar'. If that's not what you want, you have to state your intent.

Answer (score 5):

## Case `compiles1`

Your `Optional` has the generic type `Bar`, because the variable `bar` has type `Bar`.

The anonymous class of type `Foo$1` you create has `Bar` as a super type, thus the method compiles.

## Case `doesNotCompile`

Here, `Optional` has the generic type `Foo$1` and you are trying to pass an object of type `Foo$2` into `orElse` which does not have `Foo$1` as a super type. Hence the compile error.

## Case `doesNotCompile2`

Similar to `doesNotCompile`, `Optional` has the generic type `Foo$1` and you are trying to pass `bar`, a variable of type `Bar` into `orElse` which again does not have `Foo$1` as a super type.

---

## Avoiding these errors

Add a type witness to your call of `Optional::of`. This gives your `Optional` the generic type `Bar`:

```
public class Foo {

    interface Bar {
    }

    void doesNotCompile() {
        Optional.<Bar>of(new Bar() {
        }).orElse(new Bar() {
        });
    }

    void doesNotCompile2() {
        final Bar bar = new Bar() {
        };
        Optional.<Bar>of(new Bar() {
        }).orElse(bar);
    }

    void compiles1() {
        final Bar bar = new Bar() {
        };
        Optional.of(bar).orElse(new Bar() {
        });
    }
}
```